# Cannot convert from 'string' to 'TST.Domain.Entities.Enterprise'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
public async Task<RelAuthInfo> Create(RelCreateRequest entity)
{
    try
    {
        Rel nRel = _mapper.Map<Rel>(entity);
        nRel.DT_IN = DateTime.Now;
        nRel.IDA = "en-US";
        nRel.STS = "stat_status";
        nRel.FLG = "R";
        nRel.SEQ = await _repository.GetSequencial(entity.ENTERPRISE_ID);
        ++nRel.SEQ;
        nRel.PASS = Common.RandomPass(10);
        nRel.GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        string emp = entity.ENTERPRISE; // Use entity.ENTERPRISE here

        string dtProt = ((DateTime)nRel.DT_INI).ToString("yy/MM/dd").Replace("/", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(" ", "").Trim();
        nRel.NMB_PROT += dtProt + nRel.SEQ;
        nRel.REL_ID = _repository.Insert(nRel);

        foreach (ACreateRequest amem in entity.AList)
        {
            amem.RelId = nRel.REL_ID;
            amem.Prot = nRel.NMR_PROT;
            amem.Status = false;
            amem.Url = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss").Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_").Replace(" ", "_").Trim()}_{amem.Name}";
            await _amemService.SAmem(amem, entity.EMP_ID, nRel.GUID);
        }

        SendAlert(nRel, emp);

        return _mapper.Map<RelAuthInfo>(nRel);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

My goal is to use `SendAlert to send an email at the end of my` Create`method. I need to call`SendAlert`within the`Create`method.`SendAlert`has as parameters`(Rel nRel, Emp emp)`.

Comment: Which line get the error? While you mentioned that the second argument: `emp` of `SendAlert` method is `TST.Domain.Entities.Enterprise` type, why you pass the `emp` which is a string type?

Comment: I've tried everything, Yong. Even change the type "string", I even tested nRel.ENTERPRISE = emp;

string emp = entity.ENTERPRISE;

my SendAlert function is:

private void SendAlert(Rel nRel, Emp emp)
{
     string msg;
     switch (nRel.IDI)
     {
         case "en-us":
             msg = string.Format(Resource.Example, nRel.NMB_PROT, nRel.PASS, emp.TITLE);
             break;
     }
}

I'm 10 hours into 2 projects, I can't even think straight.

Comment: Seems you do not understand my comment, your `emp` in `Create` method is a `string`. But your `SendAlert` expects to receive the second argument with `Emp` type. `string` and `Emp` are two different types. You should call the `SendAlert` by providing the `Emp` instance as the second argument. `SendAlert(nRel, /* Emp instance or new Emp() */);`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `emp` to be a `string`, and then just using it to pass to the `SendAlert` method later.

```
string emp = entity.ENTERPRISE; 
...
SendAlert(nRel, emp);
```

So you are convert from `TST.Domain.Entities.Enterprise` type to a `string` type, and then trying to pass this to the method, when you don't need a string but the original type.

So instead do the following;

Remove this line, you don't need it in your current code.

```
//string emp = entity.ENTERPRISE;
```

Change this line to use the original type

```
SendAlert(nRel, entity.ENTERPRISE);
```